# Simple ASP.NET password hashing class troubles

Tags: c#, asp.net, hash, passwords, salt

I am attempting to apply some security to a project I'm completing for college. This security is somewhat glancing so I'm tempted to give up, save passwords as plaintext or converted to base64, and do something more user-obvious.

Before I give up, I'm asking SO. This is my first attempt at asking anything here so please be gentle.

I decided that implementing this MSDN code wouldn't be too hard.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa545602%28v=cs.70%29.aspx

Turns out, it really is. I'm getting the error

> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

For code

```
binarySaltValue[0] = byte.Parse( salt.Substring( 0, 2 ), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat );
```

I'm going to be honest, I don't fully understand this code.

1. What is SaltValueSize supposed to be? The provided code doesn't supply it, neither do any References. Also it's capitalised, so is it an object? Or a field in some object somewhere?
2. The variable "hash" is not defined anywhere, so I just filled it with new MD5CryptoServiceProvider(). Is this a mistake?
3. If I'm reading it right, the string "salt" is supposed to hold binary, but it doesn't at runtime, it has garbled text, meanwhile the line everything crashed at is trying to parse binary from "salt"? Why?

If anyone can fix this or supply an idiot-proof asynchronous hashing class I'd appreciate it.

( apologies for my random user name, I have no idea how that happened )

Comment: Your particular error is probably the variable `salt` contains non-numeric characters, thus salt is not in the correct format for the NumberStyle parameter (System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a basic method (no salt) to at least get you started. It just "hashes" the string coming in.

```
    private string GetHashedString(string _PW)
    {
        string _HashedPW = "";
        SHA512 sha = new SHA512CryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] result;
        StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();


        sha.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_PW));
        result = sha.Hash;

        for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
        {
            strBuilder.Append(result[i].ToString("x2"));
        }

        _HashedPW = strBuilder.ToString();
        return _HashedPW;
    }
```

Comment: You are right. I implemented a very simple "random text" generator for the salt. I tacked a random salt on the end of the plaintext, threw it through SHA256 (I don't have room for 512 but I will later).

Comment: How would you unhash it again to check the password?

Comment: You don't!

If you need to check whether the User entered the correct password you simply use the same encryption method/s used to store the password on the User's input. If the 2 encrypted values are a match then they entered identical input (hopefully not "password1234"). 

One other reason for un-hashing someone's password is for when the User forgets their password. While back in the day this was somewhat of a normal practice, nowadays you would simply verify the User's legitimacy and allow them to RESET their password - often via a link sent to the account's email address.